# How to write a string variable inside mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to implement this query :

```
if(x=1){
$update = "close = '$date'";
}
else {
$update = "open = '$date'";
}
$query = "Update table1 set $update where id=100";
mysql_query($query);
```

but I got an error, the Mysql can't execute the query ?

Comment: What is $query when you try to execute it?

Comment: `$query = "Update table1 set $update where id=100";` You better go with prepared statement for inputs.

Comment: No, I asked what it is. Do `var_dump($query);` before that line

Comment: your (x=1) should be (x==1)

Comment: @mehar in my code I write x==1 :)

Comment: @wizkid that doesn't help ?

Comment: Yes because that will print $query so you can tell us what it is

Comment: it's update a particular row inside table1 :)

Comment: @user3648409 you shoud print you query and execute in mysql and see the results

Comment: @user3648409: No it doesn't. You said you got the error: Mysql can't execute the query

Comment: it should update the table, but it is not !

Comment: Change your last line to `mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());` so you can see the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <?php
    if($x==1){
    $update = "close = '".$date."'";
    }
    else {
    $update = "open = '".$date."'";
    }
    $query = "update table1 set $update where id=100";
    mysql_query($query);
    ?>
```

Comment: This has the same bug as the question, you have `=` instead of `==` in the `if` statement.

Comment: Why do you think changing from interpolation to concatenation will fix the problem?

Comment: Dear Barmer i just edited the user code, will try to avoid it hereafter

Answer (score 0):

Put your query in the quotes. Try following :

```
if(x==1){
  $update = "close='".$date."'";
}
else {
  $update = "open = '".$date."'";
}
$query = "Update table1 set ".$update." where id=100";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Put mysql_error() to check what error are you getting from mysql

Comment: This has the same bug as the question, you have = instead of == in the if statement.

Comment: Why do you think changing from interpolation to concatenation will fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<?php


if(x==1){
$update = "close = '$date'";
}
else {
$update = "open = '$date'";
}
$query = "Update table1 set '".$update."' where id=100";
mysql_query($query);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code........

```
<?php
if($x==1){ // use $ for variables
    $update = "close = '".$date."' "; //always concatenate variables
}
else {
    $update = "open = '".$date."' ";
}
$query = "Update table1 set '".$update."' where id=100";
mysql_query($query, $connection); // don`t forget to add mysql connection 

?>
```

Comment: Why always concatenate variables? What's wrong with interpolation?

Answer (score -1):

```
Replace 
$query = Update table1 set $update where id=100;

to
$query = "Update table1 set ".$update." where id=100";
```

Comment: Why is concatenation better than variable substitution? I'm really getting tired of people who think this is the answer all the time.